# Which is the best way to transpile Node 14 to older version of Node code?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, option-type, transpiler

I love using optional and optional chaining feature in Node 14 - however, most of the serverless platforms (I want to avoid running an instance) support 12.x and below - what is the best and the cleanest way to go about doing this.

I believe Babel is more directed towards using for the frontend js - do let me know if there is a better way of doing it in the backend as well.

Answer (score 1):

Babel is the best way. I use it for the same purpose, AWS Lambda has support for Node.js 12.x runtime only.

So transpile your code using babel, and then use serverless stuff.